# Java Hibernate entity of a View without an ID

Tags: java, database, hibernate, view, primary-key

First of all, **I did search this question**, but every answer was simply "add the ID to the view", which isn't possible in my case.

To elaborate, I have a backend written in Java, and I'm using Hibernate. I need to recover data from a view with several columns, none of which are unique, which means I can't use them as an ID. Given that Hibernate demands that an @Entity have a field with an @Id annotation, this is a problem.

I cannot modify the view.

So, what would be the best solution? My current idea is to write a new IdClass to use as a composite PK.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If your domain object has to be an `@Entity` then I don't think you have any other option than try to identify a set of columns as a composite key. If this is not possible or your domain object doesn't have to be an entity then the solution depends on the technology stack you're using, i.e. here's one that's using [Spring Data JPA Projections](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a composite key using the IdClass annotation:
https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-composite-primary-keys